# response returns as undefined in script which is written for facebook login

Tags: javascript, html, .net, facebook

I want to add button to login with facebook in my web page.Also I use my own button.Because of that I write FB.login() method but it does  not work correctly.Could you help me?

```js
 window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
   FB.init({
         appId:<%=fbApi%>,
         cookie: true,
         xfbml: true,
         version: 'v3.1'
          });
          };
   function facebookLogin2() {
       debugger;
       FB.login(function (response) {
           debugger;
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log(response.name);
            }
         }, { scope: 'public_profile,email' });
         };
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&autoLogAppEvents=1&version=v3.1&appId=********';
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

```html
     <button class="btn btn-facebook btn-lg" onclick="facebookLogin2()"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i>Facebook</button>
```

Comment: "it does not work" is not a good error description, you will have to come up with some more detail than that. btw, you need to fix the indentation of your code, this looks weird.

Comment: Is your 'debugger' line interfering with the execution?

Comment: Second debugger is not affecting @TommyBs